# C# Locking on object or reference? How do you answer this?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Lets say we want to achieve thread synchronization and we use lock for this. But if a question is asked is the lock on the object or on the reference, How do we answer this question?

```
private static readonly object doSomethingLock = new object();
public static void DoSomething (SomeObject o) 
{
   lock(doSomethingLock) 
   {
       o.Update();
       // etc....
   }
}
```

Comment: You always need an object to store the lock state.  Using an object always requires using a reference.  You answer the question by saying "why do you ask?  It is not a meaningful question!"

Comment: You can't ever have multiple different references to the same object, and the same reference will never refer to different objects, so you could never observe a difference between locking on the reference or locking on the object being referenced.  Whatever the implementation does, you could never distinguish it from it doing the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lock is on the object.  Your code is equivalent to this code:

```
private static readonly object doSomethingLock = new object();
public static void DoSomething (SomeObject o) 
{
   var sameObject = doSomethingLock;
   lock(sameObject) 
   {
       o.Update();
       // etc....
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not true, the object is not locked, you can access the object in other thread and do operations with it.

Comment: @mybirthname Yes, you can access the object in another thread and do operations on it, but that doesn't change the fact that the object is in fact locked.  The semantics of an object being locked simply means that another thread cannot also acquire a lock of that object, not that it cannot access or mutate the object.

Comment: @mybirthname, I think we're interpreting the OP's question in two different ways.  The problem may just be one of terminology.  Unfortunately, I can't find good language to clarify my point.  Servy has done a better job than I probably would.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 2):

That lock is on the use of that object in that static method, not on the object globally.

If another thread tries to call that method it will be blocked until the first thread completes it's call.

It won't stop some other method accessing that object elsewhere in your code, but as long as the only access to the object is inside the lock then it's equivalent to locking the object.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for pointing this out I made one simple test to check it.

Comment: You don't lock on methods, you lock on objects.  Yes, it's true that when you lock on that object it doesn't prevent other threads from accessing it, merely from also trying to lock on it, but that doesn't change the fact that you still lock on objects.